# migrate jquery post to ajax is not the same

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i convert jquery $.post to ajax post call because I need to post ARRAY to controller.

```
$.post(url, function (data) {
                $('#myModal .modal-title').html($link.text());
                $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                //  $('#myModal .te').html($.parseHTML(data)); // this remove existing the css
                $('#myModal').modal();
            }).success(function () {
                $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
                $('#divLoading').hide();
            });
```

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify( selectedCheckbox ),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#myModal .modal-title').html($link.text());
                    $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                    //  $('#myModal .te').html($.parseHTML(data)); // this remove existing the css
                    $('#myModal').modal();
                    $('input:text:visible:first').focus();
                    $('#divLoading').hide();
                },
                error: function (request) { 
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

but is not the same!

I don't know where to put this in ajax post because in success is not ok

```
$('#myModal .modal-title').html($link.text());
                $('#myModal .te').html(data);
                //  $('#myModal .te').html($.parseHTML(data)); // this remove existing the css
                $('#myModal').modal();
```

Comment: `$.post()` can send data too.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "success is not ok"? What is "not ok" about it?

Comment: If your server actually returning a JSON result as you have requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question,
You can pass data via $.post()  also.

```
$.post(url, post_data, function(data){

}, 'json');
```

This is a shorthand version of Ajax Post. If you want to run some logic to separate out some states within the success function, you can create json array with status key in server side. In $.post() success callback, you check status for ok/not using if else block.

.success() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. You should use .done() instead.

Comment: Thank you. So first line would be: $.post(url, { ids: JSON.stringify( selectedCheckbox ) }, function (data) {

Comment: What about C# controller [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult ViewCheckedStudents(List<string> ids)? Need to be List?